# Sign in with twitter for phonegap cordova

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I want to login into my application with twitter, I'm using javascript and html. how to get twitter login page when click on twitter sign in button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do twitter login , but you need to change like , migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview and use inAppBrwoser instead of childbrowser.

http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Twitter-integration-on-PhoneGap-using-ChildBrowser-and-OAuth-for-iOS-and-Android-Platforms